# Proyectos en Stack Overflow

Tags: discusión

En lo últimos días, he visto a algún usuario que parece que le estamos haciendo entre todos "su trabajo", lanzando varias preguntas anidadas sobre las respuestas que recibe de la anterior, sin puntuar ninguna respuesta.

Cada uno es muy libre de usar SO como quiera, siempre que cumpla con las reglas de juego. En alguna ocasión, se le ha comentado esta circunstancia y se le ha dicho explicitamente que vote, y aún así hace caso omiso.

¿Qué se puede hacer en estos casos?. Yo directamente estoy omitiendo el responder las preguntas, pero creo que eso también va en perjuicio del resto, ya que acertada o errónea, mi respuesta le podría servir a alguien. ¿Qué opináis el resto?

Comment: En centro de ayuda dice .."piensa para la prosperidad" creo que se aplica bien, y coincide con lo que decís... si tu respuesta sirve a futuros lectores, no te preocupes por que un usuario no vota, igual la mayoría de los futuros visitantes tampoco lo harán. Enserio, si alguien cierra un proyecto gracias a este sitio, misión cumplida al 200%. Salu2

Comment: @rnd estás perdiendo respuestas!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza jaja.

Comment: @md `igual la mayoría de los futuros visitantes tampoco lo harán`, esto no significa que no se pueda hacer algo con usuarios (no sólo visitantes) que hacen preguntas constantemente sin emitir voto alguno

Comment: @Lamak te comento eso: hace unos días un usuario con una cuantas preguntas, que no había emitido votos ni aceptado respuestas, me acepto dos respuestas. Asi que le di una mirada a su perfil y resulto que había hecho lo mismo con otras (varias) respuestas. Existe la posibilidad que convivamos (ahora y en el futuro) con muchos otros usuarios que no saben que existen los botones up - down - mark. y que eventualmente se dan cuenta solos. Si eso pasa, es mejor, por que no fueron presionados a participar de la parte *ludica* del sitio, sino que lo hacen por si mismos.

Comment: Mi percepción (actual) es que no conviene intervenir demasiado.

Comment: @rnd también me parece bien que haya usuarios que se den cuenta de esto de forma independiente, pero definitivamente no comparto con que votar sea visto como la parte *lúdica* del sitio

Comment: @rnd porque no poner ese comentario como respuesta, a mi me parece lo mas adecuado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La verdad no me atreví a hacer esta pregunta antes, pero mi **opinión personal** es que *hay algo que no está bien con esta actitud/comportamiento*.

He respondido varias preguntas a dos usuarios *que no voy a mencionar*, pero en resumen, cada pregunta que hacían era una continuación del problema anterior, sin el esfuerzo de **responder a los comentarios** (ya sea de bienvenida y/o aclaración); básicamente resultando con una pregunta de tipo:

> Tengo X error(es) y este es mi código.

Ahora, la diferencia entre esos usuarios y yo *en cuanto a la formulación de preguntas* es que cuando acudo a Stack Overflow (*o a cualquier sitio de Stack Exchange*) solo lo hago después de haber intentado e investigado y no haya hallado soluciones.

---

Ahora, para responder a la pregunta, considero que:

*Independiente de que el OP sea nuevo o con cierta experiencia*; si puedo aportar, lo hago, ya que siempre habrá alguien mas con mas tiempo y conocimientos que deseen colaborar en el sitio.

Hay que tratar de dejar a un lado el posible *ego* que surja de estas interacciones y entender que es un sitio de **colaboración**, no de *reputación* = los votos van y vienen :)

Comment: Tal cual lo que dices Mauricio yo hago el mismo mecanismo, recurro a SO en inglés tanto como a Google y todo lo que se pueda investigar antes de caer aquí. Y así es como he logrado contestar mis propias preguntas luego también de mucha investigación. El simple hecho de que debiera preguntar todas las cuestiones con las que me encuentro día a día equivaldría a miles de preguntas diarias. Por mi parte no identifiqué todavía a los usuarios que mencionan pero siempre que puedo respondo.